# Implementing a van Emde Boas tree in Rust

Tags: rust

I wanted to implement a [van Emde Boas Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Emde_Boas_tree) in Rust, to start learning the language. Much of my implementation is derived from the pseudo-code on wikipedia, with the exception that empty subtrees are not stored.

Besides the obvious lack of docstrings on public methods, what could be improved?

```
use std::mem;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct VEBTree {
    // box is necessary for recursion
    children: Vec<Option<Box<VEBTree>>>,
    summary: Option<Box<VEBTree>>,
    // special cases of min and max:
    // if the tree is empty, min > max
    // if the tree contains only one element, min == max == that element.
    min: i64,
    max: i64,
    universe: i64,
    sqrt_universe: i64,
}

impl Clone for VEBTree {
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        VEBTree {
            children: self.children.clone(),
            summary: self.summary.clone(),
            min: self.min,
            max: self.max,
            universe: self.universe,
            sqrt_universe: self.sqrt_universe,
        }
    }
}

// helper macros

macro_rules! subtree {
    ( $self_: ident, $x: expr ) => {
        $self_.children.get($x).expect("child idx out of bounds").as_ref()
    }
}

macro_rules! summary {
    ( $self_: ident ) => {
        $self_.summary.as_ref().expect("summary not present")
    }
}

macro_rules! summary_mut {
    ( $self_: ident ) => {
        $self_.summary.as_mut().expect("summary not present")
    }
}

impl VEBTree {
    fn high(&self, x: i64) -> i64 {
        ((x as f64) / (self.sqrt_universe as f64)).floor() as i64
    }

    fn low(&self, x: i64) -> i64 {
        x % self.sqrt_universe
    }

    fn index(&self, i: i64, j: i64) -> i64 {
        i * self.sqrt_universe + j
    }

    pub fn new(max_elem: i64) -> Result<Self, &'static str> {
        if max_elem <= 1 {
            Err("universe size must be > 2")
        } else if max_elem > isize::max_value() as i64 {
            Err("universe too big")
        } else {
            // sqrt_universe: 2^(floor(log_2(universe) / 2))
            let sqrt_universe = ((((max_elem as f64).ln()) / (2f64).ln()) / 2f64).exp2() as i64;
            Ok(VEBTree {
                universe: max_elem,
                sqrt_universe: sqrt_universe,
                min: max_elem,
                max: -1,
                summary: if max_elem <= 2 {
                    None
                } else {
                    Some(Box::new(VEBTree::new(sqrt_universe).unwrap()))
                },
                children: if max_elem <= 2 {
                    vec![]
                } else {
                    vec![None; sqrt_universe as usize]
                },
            })
        }
    }

    pub fn minimum(&self) -> i64 {
        self.min
    }

    pub fn maximum(&self) -> i64 {
        self.max
    }

    pub fn universe(&self) -> i64 {
        self.universe
    }

    pub fn is_empty(&self) -> bool {
        self.min > self.max
    }

    pub fn has(&self, x: i64) -> bool {
        if x == self.min || x == self.max {
            true
        } else if self.universe == 2 || x > self.universe {
            false
        } else {
            subtree!(self, self.high(x) as usize).map_or(false, |subtree| {
                subtree.has(self.low(x))
            })
        }
    }

    fn find_in_subtree(&self, x: i64) -> Option<i64> {
        // we need to look in a different cluster. Since universe > 2, we know summary exists.
        summary!(self).find_next(self.high(x)).map_or(None, |next_index| {
            Some(self.index(next_index, subtree!(self, next_index as usize).unwrap().minimum()))
        })
    }

    pub fn find_next(&self, x: i64) -> Option<i64> {
        // base case
        if self.is_empty() {
            None
        } else if self.universe == 2 {
            if x == 0 && self.max == 1 {
                Some(1)
            } else {
                None
            }
        } else if x < self.min {
            Some(self.min)
        } else {
            let idx = self.high(x);
            let low = self.low(x);
            // look in subtrees
            subtree!(self, idx as usize).map_or_else(|| {
                self.find_in_subtree(x)
            }, |subtree| {
                let max_low = subtree!(self, idx as usize).unwrap().maximum();
                if low < max_low {
                    Some(self.index(idx, subtree.find_next(low).unwrap()))
                } else {
                    self.find_in_subtree(x)
                }
            })
        }
    }

    fn empty_insert(&mut self, x: i64) {
        self.min = x;
        self.max = x;
    }

    pub fn insert(&mut self, mut x: i64) {
        match self.is_empty() {
            true => self.empty_insert(x),
            false => {
                if self.min == self.max {
                    if x < self.min {
                        self.min = x;
                    }
                    if x > self.max {
                        self.max = x;
                    }
                }
                if x < self.min {
                    mem::swap(&mut self.min, &mut x);
                }
                if x > self.max {
                    self.max = x;
                }
                let idx = self.high(x);
                let low = self.low(x);
                let sqrt = self.sqrt_universe;
                let subtree = &mut self.children[idx as usize];
                match *subtree {
                    Some(ref mut subtree) => subtree.insert(low),
                    None => {
                        let mut new_tree = VEBTree::new(sqrt).unwrap();
                        new_tree.empty_insert(low);
                        mem::replace(subtree, Some(Box::new(new_tree)));
                        summary_mut!(self).insert(idx);
                    },
                }
            },
        };
    }

    pub fn delete(&mut self, mut x: i64) {
        match self.min == self.max && self.min == x {
            // base case - empty the tree
            true => { self.min = self.universe; self.max = -1; },
            false => {
                if self.min == x {
                    // we need to calculate the new minimum
                    self.min = if summary!(self).is_empty() {
                        self.max // return
                    } else {
                        // we need to insert the old minimum
                        x = subtree!(self, summary!(self).minimum() as usize).unwrap().minimum();
                        x
                    }
                }
                if self.max == x {
                    // we need to calculate the new maximum
                    self.max = if summary!(self).is_empty() { // only 1 element in the tree
                        self.min
                    } else {
                        subtree!(self, summary!(self).maximum() as usize).unwrap().maximum()
                    }
                }
                if !summary!(self).is_empty() {
                    // recurse
                    let idx = self.high(x);
                    let low = self.low(x);
                    let mut subtree = &mut self.children[idx as usize];
                    subtree.as_mut().unwrap().delete(low);
                    // don't store empty trees, and remove from summary as well
                    if subtree.as_ref().unwrap().is_empty() {
                        subtree.take();
                        summary_mut!(self).delete(idx);
                    }
                }
            },
        };
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The name `VEBTree` should, under Rust conventions, be `VebTree`.

The macros could be written as private methods, and I tend to think that they’d be clearer thus. I would expect them to be inlined automatically, but you could mark them `#[inline]` also; because of inlining, there will be no performance difference to the macros.

`Box` wrapping is only needed to provide indirection so that recursive data types work. `summary` thus needs it, but `children` doesn’t.

Your `Clone` implementation could (and thus should) be replaced with `#[derive(Clone)]`.

You check if `max_elem <= 1`, but then report as the error that universe size must be > 2; the clause, however, would correspond to > 1.

Now, concerning the equation; for starters, `((((max_elem as f64).ln()) / (2f64).ln()) / 2f64).exp2() as i64` should be written as `((max_elem as f64).ln() / 2f64.ln() / 2f64).exp2() as i64`—superfluous parentheses hamper reading. But there is a more significant issue at stake: the actual equation being calculated.

The comment gives this equation: $$2^{floor\left(\frac{log_2 x}2\right)}$$

But the code calculates this equation: $$floor\left(2^\frac{log_2 x}2\right)$$

These give quite different results; the comment would yield only powers of two, but the latter will yield all integers, and might as well be `max_elem.sqrt()`.

I feel that `if max_elem <= 2` would be clearer as `if max_elem == 2`, seeing as `max_elem > 1` has already been asserted.

In `insert`: `match x { true => …, false => … }` would normally be nicer written as `if x { … } else { … }`. One less indentation level, and a more natural way of expressing it.

In `delete`: `summary!(self)` is being called quite a few times; it feels like it should be possible to remove some of them, but I haven’t thought about it much at all.

Comment: Regarding the `match x { true => ..., false => ... }`, I did that to mimic guards in Haskell, which would be written similarly, but I do agree that it would be nicer indentation with an `if`. Also - nice catch on the math error, that's a result of translation from a different language.